# ListView SetAdapter error

Tags: java, android

I was trying to set an adapter on my listview and they tell me this error

```
  Constructor 'com.test.test.MainActivity.Listview1Adapter.Listview1Adapter() can not be applied to '(java.util.ArrayList<java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>>)'
```

Here is my code:

```
  listview1.setAdapter(new Listview1Adapter(list));
    }
```

Comment: Let's show `ListView1Adapter` constructor

Answer (score 1):

You can set an adapter to a `listview` like this:

`ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);`

And then:

`listview1.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);`

Answer (score 0):

This is because the implementation in your code is wrong.

You are supposed to write using an ArrayAdapter if you want to connect the list and the listView.

```
  listview1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));
```